# Little-endian byte order

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, endianness

I'm continuously sending arrays of pixel values from LabVIEW to a C-program through TCP/IP connection. The C-program receives a stream of bytes, so I'm converting the bytes to uint32 using the following code to print all the pixel values in an array. Does anyone know how to switch the byte-order to little-endian in this case?:

```
WSADATA wsa;
SOCKET s , new_socket;
struct sockaddr_in server , client;
int c;
int iResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
typedef unsigned int uint32_t;
unsigned int i;
size_t len;
uint32_t* p;
uint32_t* endp;
uint32_t value;

p = (uint32_t*)((void*)recvbuf);

do
{
    iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    len = iResult/sizeof(uint32_t);

    for(i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
    value = p[i];
    }   
    printf("%d\n", value);  
} 
while ( iResult > 0 );

    closesocket(new_socket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`htonl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/htonl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `htonl()` to convert a 32-bit integer from host byte order to network byte order before sending it, and use `ntohl()` to convert a 32-bit integer from network byte order to host byte order after receiving it.  There are also `htons()` and `ntohs()` for 16-bit integers.  Let the functions decide how to convert the values for you.  On little endian systems, the functions are implemented to perform actual conversions.  On big endian systems, the functions are implemented as no-ops.

Comment: I'm sending the byte stream as little endian from LabVIEW. So I also have to switch to litte-endian in this code, right ?

Comment: Network byte order is big endian. If LabVIEW is sending the data in little endian instead, and your app is running on a little endian system, then it does not need to do anything special, the data is already in the correct endian. But if LabVIEW is sending in little endian and your app is running on a big endian system, then you need to convert the values. Your code operates in whatever endian the CPU natively uses, so you have to be aware of endian issues whenever your app's data interacts with outside systems.

Answer (score 0):

Use the family of macros/functions http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs to send data over the network. Then you will not have any problems at all.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited your answer by mistake. Just fixed, sorry!